# Embed a web browser in a cross platform Gtk application

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm, gtk3

I need to embed a very simple browser ( can parse HTML, and JS Ext ) in a Gtk Widget hopefully in gtkmm. I looked into gtkmozembed, but the c++ wrapper is very out dated, so I tried to just write it in C, but I'm already committed to Gtk+ 3.0, and gtkmozembed doesn't work with Gtk+ 3.0. Is there a way to just extend Gtk::Widget and put a gecko parser in it? Can't really find any gecko documentation, I keep getting redirected to gtkmozembed.

Any ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
@Mark After I tried using Webkitgtk, I get the following output and the application crashes.

```
** (ttocui_gtk:16360): DEBUG: NP_Initialize
** (ttocui_gtk:16360): DEBUG: NP_Initialize succeeded
** (ttocui_gtk:16360): DEBUG: NP_Initialize
** (ttocui_gtk:16360): DEBUG: NP_Initialize succeeded
** (ttocui_gtk:16360): DEBUG: NP_Initialize
** (ttocui_gtk:16360): DEBUG: NP_Initialize succeeded
** (ttocui_gtk:16360): DEBUG: NP_Initialize
** (ttocui_gtk:16360): DEBUG: NP_Initialize succeeded
** (ttocui_gtk:16360): DEBUG: NP_Initialize
** (ttocui_gtk:16360): DEBUG: NP_Initialize succeeded
** (ttocui_gtk:16360): DEBUG: NP_Initialize
** (ttocui_gtk:16360): DEBUG: NP_Initialize succeeded
** (ttocui_gtk:16360): DEBUG: NP_Initialize
** (ttocui_gtk:16360): DEBUG: NP_Initialize succeeded
** (ttocui_gtk:16360): DEBUG: NP_Initialize
** (ttocui_gtk:16360): DEBUG: NP_Initialize succeeded

(ttocui_gtk:16360): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_foreach: assertion `hash_table != NULL' failed

(ttocui_gtk:16360): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_insert_internal: assertion `hash_table != NULL' failed

(ttocui_gtk:16360): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_lookup: assertion `hash_table != NULL' failed
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** ERROR: no valid NPP -> PluginInstance mapping found

(ttocui_gtk:16360): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_lookup: assertion `hash_table != NULL' failed
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** ERROR: no valid NPP -> PluginInstance mapping found

(ttocui_gtk:16360): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_lookup: assertion `hash_table != NULL' failed

(ttocui_gtk:16360): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_insert_internal: assertion `hash_table != NULL' failed

(ttocui_gtk:16360): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_insert_internal: assertion `hash_table != NULL' failed

(ttocui_gtk:16360): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_find: assertion `hash_table != NULL' failed

(ttocui_gtk:16360): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_insert_internal: assertion `hash_table != NULL' failed

(ttocui_gtk:16360): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_lookup: assertion `hash_table != NULL' failed
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** ERROR: no valid NPP -> PluginInstance mapping found

(ttocui_gtk:16360): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_lookup: assertion `hash_table != NULL' failed
ttocui_gtk: /build/buildd/nspluginwrapper-1.2.2/src/npw-rpc.c:1225: do_recv_NPObject: Assertion `npobj != ((void *)0)' failed.
*** NSPlugin Viewer  *** ERROR: NPN_GetProperty() wait for reply: Connection reset by peer
*** NSPlugin Viewer  *** WARNING:(/build/buildd/nspluginwrapper-1.2.2/src/npw-viewer.c:898):invoke_NPN_GetValue: assertion failed: (rpc_method_invoke_possible(g_rpc_connection))
Aborted
*** NSPlugin Viewer  *** WARNING: unhandled variable 18 (<unknown variable>) in NPN_GetValue()
*** NSPlugin Viewer  *** WARNING:(/build/buildd/nspluginwrapper-1.2.2/src/npw-viewer.c:898):invoke_NPN_GetValue: assertion failed: (rpc_method_invoke_possible(g_rpc_connection))
```

The .js file is included in the head tag of my html pages...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ext3.2.1/resources/css/ext-all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ext3.2.1/resources/css/xtheme-access.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/ext3.2.1/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ext3.2.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just thought I'd come back and let anyone who cares know that our solution was to use Gtkmozembed. Only problem with it is that Gtkmozembed only runs using gtk+ 2 and I'm using gtk+ 3. The two can not exist in the same process, and I'm not migrating either project. So I'm running gtkmozembed in a child process that I use pipes to communicate with, and a GtkPlug that renders the widget in my project.

This solution is a little hokey, but it gets the job done, and the browser is embedded.

Answer (score 8):

Neither does gtkmozembed work with new versions of Gecko, if my memory serves me. What you are looking for is [WebkitGTK](http://www.webkitgtk.org/), at least if you're not specifically tied to Gecko.

Comment: Mozilla/Firefox is not embeddable anymore since 4.0

Comment: I'm definitely not tied to any concept/implementation at this point. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @ptomato any chance you know why WebkitGTK doesn't like POST data [(SO Question)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771942/webkitgtk-wont-cant-find-post-data)? I'm still looking for an alternative to gtkmozembed.

Answer (score 5):

As an addendum to @ptomato's answer.  WebKitGTK is the way to go.  I do not know of a gtkmm/C++ wrapper for it, but I am currently using it from a gtkmm project quite successfully (luckily, gtkmm/C++ allows you to mix in the C gtk quite easily):

```
WebKitWebView* pWebKitView = WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW (webkit_web_view_new ());
gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (pSomeContainer->gobj()), GTK_WIDGET (pWebKitView));
```

And off you go...

Comment: I don't know how mature these c++ bindings are, but [this](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/ApplicationsGtk#Cgtkmmbindings) is from the Webkit wiki.

Comment: But going cross platform with WebKitGTK is something that is not easy. You will see when you try to get it compiled on windows.

Comment: Thanks @Mark! I will definitely give this a shot, but @Lothar makes a good point. I need this to compile in windows which is why I was going to go with Gecko, or something lightweight and portable. I don't need security or really rich web features, I just need to parse HTML, and Javascript ( Ext JS Framework ).

Comment: @ptomato, that project looks kind of old. I couldn't even get it to build when I was researching this the other day.

Comment: @Mark, Okay, after fighting with the 'gstreamer' dependencies I finally got around to giving this a shot, and it works really well, except that it won't parse the JavaScript EXT libraries. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @paullj1, what do you mean by "won't parse"?  Does it return an error?  How are you sourcing in the .js script files?  I've never used it with ext.js but I have with jQuery without problems.

Comment: @paullj1: clarifications (such as error messages) should go in your question, not other people's answers. SO is a Q&A site, not a forum. Better still, post as a new question, since that's what you have.

Comment: @Mark, I've posted a new question, and added the output of the application to this one. Any thoughts? http://stackoverflow.com/q/7221567/875375

Comment: @paullj, sorry I am on the east coast of the US and currently without electricity.  My internet time is limited.  From what I see of your error though, they are from nspluginwrapper, are you embedding flash or something?

Comment: @Mark, Sorry it's been so long, and thank you for your help in the past. I solved the 'crash' problem, it turns out it was an OS / outdated library issue. Now I'm trying to figure out why webkit won't do a POST method. GET works fine, but for obvious security reasons, I need to do a POST method. It's probably not even a webkit problem, but do you have any ideas?

Comment: @paullj, could you show some sample code?  Perhaps open a new question with the details.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the quick response, I really appreciate it. Here's a link to the question I just posted with the code I'm using: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771942/webkitgtk-wont-cant-find-post-information) Thanks again.